# Skip the current row COUNT and sum up the other COUNTS for current key with Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

My input:

```
 val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("0","car1", "success"),
  ("0","car1", "success"),
  ("0","car3", "success"),
  ("0","car2", "success"),
  ("1","car1", "success"),
  ("1","car2", "success"),
  ("0","car3", "success")
)).toDF("id", "item", "status")
```

My intermediary group by output looks like this:

```
val df2 = df.groupBy("id", "item").agg(count("item").alias("occurences"))
```

```
+---+----+----------+
| id|item|occurences|
+---+----+----------+
|  0|car3|         2|
|  0|car2|         1|
|  0|car1|         2|
|  1|car2|         1|
|  1|car1|         1|
+---+----+----------+
```

The output I would like is:
Calculating the sum of **occurrences of item** **skipping the occurrences value** of the current id's item.

For example in the output table below, **car3** appeared for **id "0"** 2 times, **car 2** appeared 1 time and **car 1** appeared 2 times.

So for id "0", the sum of other occurrences for its "car3" item would be value of car2(1) + car1(2) = 3.
For the same id "0", the sum of other occurrences for its "car2" item would be value of car3(2) + car1(2) = 4.

This continues for the rest. Sample output

```
+---+----+----------+----------------------+
| id|item|occurences| other_occurences_sum |
+---+----+----------+----------------------+
|  0|car3|         2|          3           |<- (car2+car1) for id 0
|  0|car2|         1|          4           |<- (car3+car1) for id 0  
|  0|car1|         2|          3           |<- (car3+car2) for id 0
|  1|car2|         1|          1           |<- (car1) for id 1
|  1|car1|         1|          1           |<- (car2) for id 1
+---+----+----------+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's perfect target for a window function.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.sum

val w = Window.partitionBy("id")

df2.withColumn(
  "other_occurences_sum", sum($"occurences").over(w) - $"occurences"
).show
// +---+----+----------+--------------------+     
// | id|item|occurences|other_occurences_sum|
// +---+----+----------+--------------------+
// |  0|car3|         2|                   3|
// |  0|car2|         1|                   4|
// |  0|car1|         2|                   3|
// |  1|car2|         1|                   1|
// |  1|car1|         1|                   1|
// +---+----+----------+--------------------+
```

where `sum($"occurences").over(w)` is a sum of all occurrences for the current id. Of course `join` is also valid:

```
df2.join(
  df2.groupBy("id").agg(sum($"occurences") as "total"), Seq("id")
).select(
    $"*", ($"total" - $"occurences") as "other_occurences_sum"
).show

// +---+----+----------+--------------------+
// | id|item|occurences|other_occurences_sum|
// +---+----+----------+--------------------+
// |  0|car3|         2|                   3|
// |  0|car2|         1|                   4|
// |  0|car1|         2|                   3|
// |  1|car2|         1|                   1|
// |  1|car1|         1|                   1|
// +---+----+----------+--------------------+
```